# Predictive model decision tree

Tags: r, r-caret

I want to build a predictive model using decision tree classification in R. I used this code:

```
library(rpart)
library(caret)
DataYesNo <- read.csv('DataYesNo.csv', header=T)
summary(DataYesNo)
worktrain <- sample(1:50, 40)
worktest  <- setdiff(1:50, worktrain)
DataYesNo[worktrain,]
DataYesNo[worktest,]
M      <- ncol(DataYesNo)
input  <- names(DataYesNo)[1:(M-1)]                 
target <- “YesNo”                                       
tree   <- rpart(YesNo~Var1+Var2+Var3+Var4+Var5,
                data=DataYesNo[worktrain, c(input,target)],
                method="class",
                parms=list(split="information"),
                control=rpart.control(usesurrogate=0, maxsurrogate=0))

summary(tree) 
plot(tree)
text(tree)
```

I got just one root (`Var3`) and two leafs (`yes`, `no`). I'm not sure about this result. How can I get the confusion matrix, accuracy, sensitivity, and specificity?
Can I get them with the `caret` package?

Answer (score 0):

If you use your model to make predictions on your test set, you can use `confusionMatrix()` to get the measures you're looking for.

Something like this...

```
predictions <- predict(tree, worktest)
cmatrix <- confusionMatrix(predictions, worktest$YesNo)
print(cmatrix)
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you create a confusion matrix, other measures can also be obtained - I don't remember them at the moment.

According to your example, the confusion matrix can be obtained as following.

```
fitted <- predict(tree, DataYesNo[worktest, c(input,target)])
actual <- DataYesNo[worktest, c(target)]
confusion <- table(data.frame(fitted = fitted, actual = actual))
```